# Некорректное отображение графического меню в ie7

Tags: drupal, internet-explorer, css

Здравствуйте!

Мой сайт (http://obedcafe.ru) написан на дрюпале и работает корректно во всех браузерах, кроме ie7. В ie7 картинки отображаются неправильно, с белыми полосами. Помогите, пожалуйста, решить данный вопрос. ))

Comment: С белыми полосами? А можно скриншот, а то у меня нет никакого эксплорера, чтобы посмотреть, тем более IE7.. небось с прозрачностью какой-нибудь лаг..

Comment: Здравствуйте! Если Вы есть в контакте, то посмотрите, пожалуйста, вот эту ссылку: http://vkontakte.ru/id15905498?27860#/photo15905498_228854354 ))

Comment: Поставила opacity равное единице, не помогло.

Comment: Не понимаю, зачем такой сайт было в Drupal делать. Достаточно знать HTML и CSS, чтобы такое сделать. А проблема как раз возникла из-за того, что вы как раз и в друпале сайт сделали, никогда таких глюков не видел. Вот сейчас сам для кафедры сайт сделал полностью кроссбраузерный, то есть во всех браузерах работает правильно. Да, и я нашел кое-какие ошибки, когда ваш сайт проверял: у вас вверху, в шапке, при маленьких разрешениях монитора изображения начинают налазить друг на друга. И подвал, то есть нижняя часть, повторяется и это видно, причем создается некрасивый вид.

Comment: @Perl Уважаемый участник, если Вы хотите оставить свои контакты, Вы всегда можете указать их в своем профиле: он создан специально для этих целей.

Comment: Начальник сказал -- вот и пишу на drupal. Это мой первый проект. Спасибо большое за советы, но давайте всё-таки сначала решим главную проблему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо

```
font-size: 0;
```

надо написать

```
text-indent: -9000px;
```

finito!